# How and where to store access token securely

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, jwt

I know this question has been asked many times but frankly I have not seen an answer that satisfies the criteria I have.

So I have a ASP.NET WEB API that issues an access token (JWT) when user/pass are provided. At the moment requests are coming from an SPA application. The problem I have is storing the access token so it can be resent to the API from JavaScript.
So far it looks like there are 2 commonly suggested options

- HTML5 Web Store
- Cookies

But none of these is actually secure since they are not protected from XSS and CSRF. And on top of that it makes token easily accessible.

Any options you would suggest ?

Comment: Here's a [good resource](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/27/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/) if you haven't already seen/read it.

Comment: Thanks I've seen it. I just don't see how it answers the question)) I still can get an access token and send requests directly to API

Comment: The specific section on [XSS and C/XSRF](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/27/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/#xss-xsrf)? It doesn't protect your API from something like `curl` for a direct request however - though I'm personally unsure (and would like to know) how to accomplish the attack (assuming anti-xss is in place) - in other words, how would some _else_ be able to grab that token (its a given that you can access _your own token_)?

Comment: @EdSF if I'll set httpOnly cookie how I'll get the value from JavaSript ?

Comment: I think that section says that tokens are vulnerable to XSS _if your app is/in the first place_ (mitigating factors are `iat` and `exp`)

Comment: So does this mean that there is no really secure option for my scenario ? Am I missing something?

Comment: And BTW what if I will have httponly cookie and access it in server controller and put it in a hidden field so it will be accessible by JS on my site. Or this will even make things worse ?

Comment: If your app is already vulnerable to XSS then your tokens are - so if you deal with XSS then that mitigates vulnerability (JWT `iat` and `exp` can help mitigate, but doesn't prevent). For XSRF, your token _isn't_ sent automatically (cookies would by browser). EOD, a client must somehow persist some "identifier" to "present" to a server for some access. The gist is dealing with XSS is relatively easier/more well known than how to deal with XSRF.

Answer (score 0):

Web store is vulnerable to XSS. Cookie is vulnerable to XSS if not HTTPONLY. Cookie is vulnerable to CSRF when not STRICT, even if it is HTTPONLY.

So I think we can **store the access token in memory**. Issue with that is there is no persistence between page refreshes. So for persistence we can store a refresh token in web storage or a cookie and whenever we do not have an access token we can get a new one silently with a refresh token.

When using an identity server a refresh token will not be of any use to any unauthorised client.

So if they XSS and steal the refresh token or CSRF with the refresh token cookie they cannot impersonate the user or get the access token.